# Web8 | What are the configurations for setting OAuth properly for all Microservices

Tags: web8, topology-manager, authorization, microservices

If we follow Web 8 Installation instructions, by default we install all the Microservices with `OAuth/Rules Enabled` in `ambient_conf`(with `registration` account).
Also it is observed that there are more roles/accounts(`cmuser`/`cduser`/`implementer` etc.) placed in the config ([More Info here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/14581/1449))

I had tried `registration` user everywhere while setting up topology and publishing failed .Later found that many of us have faced issues with connecting with one or other service (`invalid_grant/authorization` `errors`) and most of us are `Disabling` OAuth as a workaround.

**Questions-**

Is there a recommendation in place to use particular users as `clientId` for OAuth while setting up topology(to connect to discovery/other services) so that not only Publishing but also connection to various services from different interaction points(`Deployer Service` while Publishing/`Content Services` while retrieving Content..) is seamless?

Any related `SDL docs` links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detailed description of Roles is documented [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-FB988CD0-0D03-44EC-960A-5E483FF697C5).

`registration` user is used only for registering capabilities in discovery service.

When setting up topology, you need to use `cmuser` [Reference here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8)

For retrieving content (CD side), you should be using `cduser`

Also you can check [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/14593/1743) on `Roles`

Comment: I see, actually i didn't do single server installation and this `cmsuser` thing is only mentioned in that section & missing from normal installation section [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-52727C62-2976-476F-8F83-6A980DC585E7)