# Failed to authenticate with the token provider

Tags: web8.5

While configuring Deployer environment on Topology manager using the commandlet Add-TtmCdEnvironment, I am running into the below issue.
I have done a quick install of microservices as mentioned of web 8.5

```
PS C:\Softwares\SDL Web 8.5\SDL Web 8.5\Database\mssql> Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id devdeployer -EnvironmentPurpose Staging -DiscoveryEndpointUrl http://devdeployer:8082/discovery.svc -AuthenticationType OAuth

cmdlet Add-TtmCdEnvironment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ClientId: cmuser
ClientSecret: Reg1str@t10nP@ssw0rd
Add-TtmCdEnvironment : Unable to save item of type 'CdEnvironmentData' with id 'devdeployer'.
One or more errors occurred.
Authorization failed while attempting to communicate with CD Discovery Service 'http://devdeployer:8082/discovery.svc'. Please make sure the proper credentials have
been configured in the CD Environment 'devdeployer'.
One or more errors occurred.
Failed to authenticate with the token provider.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id devdeployer -EnvironmentPurpose Sta ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:AddCdEnvironmentCommand) [Add-TtmCdEnvironment], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdEnvironmentCommand
```

I have also configured and registered the token service. 
Not sure what else I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Detailed description of Roles is documented [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-FB988CD0-0D03-44EC-960A-5E483FF697C5).

`registration` user is used only for registering capabilities in discovery service.

When setting up topology, you need to use `cmuser` Reference [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8)

For retrieving content (CD side), you should be using `cduser`

Also you can check [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-microservice-roles-in-sdl-web-8/14593#14593) on `Roles`

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is missing lot of steps. Checked cd_ambient_conf.xml for the password for cmuser and got it.

Comment: The answer [here](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/14625/1449) makes things simpler and helps to remember use of different users.